# Disable and Enable Arrowkeys by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where first I need to disable keyboard arrow keys and after some processing again Enable it,for this I write this jquery function

```
function DisableArrowKeys() {
        var ar = new Array(37, 38, 39, 40);
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            var key = e.which;
            if ($.inArray(key, ar) > -1) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false; 
           }
            return true;
        });
    }
```

this function can disable arrow keys,after some processing I need to enable arrow key for this I made changes in the function like below

```
function EnableArrowKeys() {
        var ar = new Array(37, 38, 39, 40);
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            var key = e.which;
            if ($.inArray(key, ar) > -1) {              
                return true;
            }           
        });
    }
```

But when we call that function it does not enable arrowkeys.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep a reference to your disabling function, and unbind it when you are ready to accept arrow keys once more.  Something like:

```
var ar = new Array(37, 38, 39, 40);
var disableArrowKeys = function(e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, ar)>=0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

$(document).keydown(disableArrowKeys);

// then when you are ready to enable, unbind the function...
$(document).unbind('keydown', disableArrowKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second handler (attached in `EnableArrowKeys` function) is not cancelling the first one. jQuery event handlers are chained:

[If there are multiple handlers registered, they will always execute in the order in which they were bound.](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

So, use [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function in `EnableArrowKeys` function instead of adding another handler.

```
function EnableArrowKeys() {
    $(document).unbind('keydown');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var DisableArrowKeys = function(e){
    if ($.inArray(e.which, ar) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
$(document).bind("keydown", DisableArrowKeys);
```

and then to unbind:

```
$(document).unbind("keydown", DisableArrowKeys);
```