# React-Slick Carousel - Disable keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, carousel, slick.js

Can anyone help me how can i disable keyboard arrows, to be more clearly when i press the right or left arrow at keyboard i dont want to move forward on carousel slider.

The point is to disable the arrows on keyboards (not moving forward or backward).
[Make keyboard: false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k64lz.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable and Enable Arrowkeys by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467604/disable-and-enable-arrowkeys-by-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your help @KingReload but its not the right answer that im looking for.

Comment: Doesn't look like the `react-slick` API allows you to disable arrow keys controls.

Comment: Maybe there's no easy way to do it, you may dowload react-slick source, then hack into it ^^ (to disable the function where they handle the keyboard) to disable keyboard arrows. I have done the same thing, but for other features, not for the keyboard issues!

Comment: @dogui Good point, but i found the solution on the documentation of react-slick.
The solution is that i only need to add `accessibility: false`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

React Slick has props "accessibility" you need set it to "false" in your  component.
Also slider has many ather props in doc https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api.